# Basic question about transformation of energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy

They teach us that energy can't be created or lost, it only changes its form. So when a rock is on a hill, it has potential energy. If you drop it, the potential energy transforms into kinetic energy. Once it hit the ground, it has no potential and no kinetic energy - so where is it?

Comment: Lost as heat and sound. Or maybe the rock broke into pieces. That will increase its potential energy too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the collision is [inelastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision) (i.e. the rock sticks to the ground and doesn't bounce), all of its kinetic energy is converted to vibrational energy, in the form of heat and sound.

However, since [momentum is conserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation), the rock will also add its momentum to the Earth (it will actually move the planet by an infinitesimal amount).

Also note that, at the bottom of the hill, the rock has "zero" potential energy only by definition of the current problem. It still has plenty of potential energy with respect to the center of the Earth, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The collision of the body with the ground, in practice, is not elastic. Hence by the impact, the ground absorbs some of the energy, some part of it loses as sound and heat. The energy is not lost. If the ground do not take any energy, then the object may shatter into pieces.